# Uncaught reference error: image not defined

Tags: javascript

When I run this in google chrome (or any other browser) I get the error
    Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:lightgrey}
</style>
<title>Play Pixel Draw</title>
<h1>Pixel Draw!</h1>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on the white squares to change that square blue. Make whatever you want!</p>
<hr>
<img id="first" onclick="changeImage()" src="square1.png" width="50" height="50">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeImage() {
var square = document.getElementById('first');
if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
    image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
} else {
    image.src = "square1.png";
}
}
```

Assuming that all of the pictures are in the right place, how can I fix this?

Comment: Define `image` (`var image = this;`).

Comment: `var square..` followed by `if (image...` - presumably they should be the same?

Comment: You can't use `match` like that either. `match` expects a regular expression.

Comment: @Andy Indeed.  Though _technically_ this will be converted to a regex, and would happen to match anyway...

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Andy [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Parameters): _"If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj)."_

Comment: Haha, I just looked at that and only got as far as "str.match(regexp)" and thought, yeah, that's all I need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reference to an `image` variable in the code below - it is, as the error suggests, not defined.

```
function changeImage() {
    var square = document.getElementById('first');
    if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
        image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "square1.png";
    }
}
```

All you have to do is change the square variable to image, I assume.

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('first');
    if (image.src.match("square1.png")) {
        image.src = "squareblue1.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "square1.png";
    }
}
```